# Serilog- grouping custom enrichers

Tags: c#, logging, serilog, appsettings, serilog-aspnetcore

I created custom enrichers and registered them in Serilog. I don't want to register every enriched to appsetting.json.
My question is how can I group this custom registers and only add this group name to appsettings.json

UserNameEnricher.cs

```
public class UserNameEnricher: ILogEventEnricher
    {
        public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory pf)
        {
            var propertyName = "UserName";
            var propertyValue = "HUZEYFE";
            var newProperty = pf.CreateProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(newProperty);
        }
    }
```

AddDateTimeNowEnricher.cs

```
public class AddDateTimeNowEnricher: ILogEventEnricher
    {
        public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory pf)
        {
            var propertyName = "DateTimeNow";
            var propertyValue = DateTime.Now;
            var newProperty = pf.CreateProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(newProperty);
        }
    }
```

And this is enricher registerer

```
public static class LoggingExtensions
    {
        public static LoggerConfiguration WithAddDateTimeNow(
            this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrich)
        {
            if (enrich == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enrich));

            return enrich.With<AddDateTimeNowEnricher>();

        }

        public static LoggerConfiguration WithUserName(
            this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrich)
        {
            if (enrich == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enrich));

            return enrich.With<UserNameEnricher>();

        }
    }
```

Comment: If these enrichers are not to be used separately then I would not create multiples enrichers. Whole point of having separate enrichers is to be able to configure them separately.

Comment: Do you mean add more than one property into an enricher class? 
If I add too many properties it not looks good. For example I want to do a StatsEnricher with stats properties and UserEnricher with user-specific properties. Then I want to create a single LoggerConfiguration to use these enricher groups. So I can import  enricher groups with only one LoggerConfiguration. Different LoggerConfiguration could be used later.